# How to load Vector Assets from the assets folder in Android?

Tags: android, assets, drawable

If I add a vector image (test.svg) using the Vector Asset it generates XML file in  /res/drawable/test.xml and then I can create drawable using:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
```

My question is if there is a way I can create drawable using (*SVG) or (*XML)-vector assets file, from my assets folder.

I have tried using [svg-android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android) using:

```
SVG svg = new SVGBuilder().readFromAsset(getAssets(), "test.svg").build();
```

Some svg images are loaded, while other are not followed by error message, and the repo is no longer being developed or maintained.

I have tried using InputStream and XmlPullParser, with no success

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            //InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("test.svg");
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("test.xml");
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            factory.setValidating(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(inputStream, "UTF_8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```